# Google Map v3 - Jquery Demo - Map Marker

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I'm utilizing this demo on a new project:
http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/jquery-google-maps-mobile.html#directions_map

Only thing I'm changing is I'll have the destination preloaded on the map zoomed in a bit.

What I'm having a rough time working out is... how do I get the map marker to show on the destination location on load?

Here's a cleaned up version of the working map (just need to link up to modernizer). If anyone can modify to show the markers on the map (destination on load, and when dropping in the start point which changes the map), you'd be a lifesaver.

thanks very much
-Dave

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
        <head>
        <title>jQuery mobile with Google maps - Google maps jQuery plugin</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/css/jquery-mobile-1.0/jquery.mobile.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/css/mobile.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&libraries=places"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/modernizr.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/demos/js/demo.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ui/jquery.ui.map.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ui/jquery.ui.map.services.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://jquery-ui-map.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ui/jquery.ui.map.extensions.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var mobileDemo = { 'center': '40.74843,-73.98566', 'zoom': 18 };

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            $('#basic_map').live('pageinit', function() {
                demo.add('basic_map', function() {
                    $('#map_canvas').gmap({'center': mobileDemo.center, 'zoom': mobileDemo.zoom, 'disableDefaultUI':true, 'callback': function() {
                        var self = this;
                        self.addMarker({'position': this.get('map').getCenter() }).click(function() {
                            self.openInfoWindow({ 'content': 'Hello World!' }, this);
                        });
                    }}); 
                }).load('basic_map');
            });

            $('#basic_map').live('pageshow', function() {
                demo.add('basic_map', function() { $('#map_canvas').gmap('refresh'); }).load('basic_map');
            });

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            $('#directions_map').live('pageinit', function() {
                demo.add('directions_map', function() {
                    $('#map_canvas_1').gmap({'center': mobileDemo.center, 'zoom': mobileDemo.zoom, 'disableDefaultUI':true, 'callback': function() {
                        var self = this;
                        self.set('getCurrentPosition', function() {
                            self.refresh();
                            self.getCurrentPosition( function(position, status) {
                                if ( status === 'OK' ) {
                                    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude)
                                    self.get('map').panTo(latlng);
                                    self.search({ 'location': latlng }, function(results, status) {
                                        if ( status === 'OK' ) {
                                            $('#from').val(results[0].formatted_address);
                                        }
                                    });
                                } else {
                                    alert('Unable to get current position');
                                }
                            });
                        });
                        $('#submit').click(function() {
                            self.displayDirections({ 'origin': $('#from').val(), 'destination': $('#to').val(), 'travelMode': google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING }, { 'panel': document.getElementById('directions')}, function(response, status) {
                                ( status === 'OK' ) ? $('#results').show() : $('#results').hide();
                            });
                            return false;
                        });
                    }});
                }).load('directions_map');
            });

            $('#directions_map').live('pageshow', function() {
                demo.add('directions_map', $('#map_canvas_1').gmap('get', 'getCurrentPosition')).load('directions_map');
            });

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            $('#gps_map').live('pageinit', function() {
                demo.add('gps_map', function() {
                    $('#map_canvas_2').gmap({'center': mobileDemo.center, 'zoom': mobileDemo.zoom, 'disableDefaultUI':true, 'callback': function(map) {
                        var self = this;
                        self.watchPosition(function(position, status) {
                            if ( status === 'OK' ) {
                                var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
                                if ( !self.get('markers').client ) {
                                    self.addMarker({ 'id': 'client', 'position': latlng, 'bounds': true });
                                } else {
                                    self.get('markers').client.setPosition(latlng);
                                    map.panTo(latlng);
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }});
                }).load('gps_map');
            });

            $('#gps_map').live('pageshow', function() {
                demo.add('gps_map', function() { $('#map_canvas_2').gmap('refresh'); }).load('gps_map');
            });

            $('#gps_map').live("pagehide", function() {
                demo.add('gps_map', function() { $('#map_canvas_2').gmap('clearWatch'); }).load('gps_map');
            });

            ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

            $('#places').live('pageinit', function() {
                demo.add('places_1', function() {
                    $('#map_canvas_3').gmap({'center': mobileDemo.center, 'zoom': mobileDemo.zoom, 'disableDefaultUI':true, 'callback': function() {
                        var self = this;
                        var control = self.get('control', function() {
                            $(self.el).append('<div id="control"><div><input id="places-search" class="ui-bar-d ui-input-text ui-body-null ui-corner-all ui-shadow-inset ui-body-d ui-autocomplete-input" type="text"/></div></div>');
                            self.autocomplete($('#places-search')[0], function(ui) {
                                self.clear('markers');
                                self.set('bounds', null);
                                self.placesSearch({ 'location': ui.item.position, 'radius': '5000' }, function(results, status) {
                                    if ( status === 'OK' ) {
                                        $.each(results, function(i, item) {
                                            self.addMarker({ 'id': item.id, 'position': item.geometry.location, 'bounds':true }).click(function() {
                                                self.openInfoWindow({'content': '<h4>'+item.name+'</h4>'}, this);
                                            });
                                        });
                                    }
                                });
                            });
                            return $('#control')[0];
                        });
                        self.addControl(new control(), 1);
                    }});
                }).load('places_1');
            });

            $('#places').live('pageshow', function() {
                demo.add('places_2', function() { $('#map_canvas_3').gmap('refresh'); }).load('places_2');
            });

        </script>
        </head>
<body>
<div id="directions_map" data-role="page"><div data-role="content">

    <div class="ui-bar-c ui-corner-all ui-shadow" style="padding:1em;">
      <div id="map_canvas_1" style="height:300px;"></div>
          <p>
            <label for="from">From</label>
            <input id="from" class="ui-bar-c" type="text" value="" />
          </p>
          <p>
            <label for="to">To</label>
            <input id="to" class="ui-bar-c" type="text" value="350 5th Ave, New York, NY 10118" />
          </p>
          <a id="submit" href="#" data-role="button" data-icon="search">Get directions</a>
      </div>

    <div id="results" class="ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow" style="display:none;">
      <div class="ui-li ui-li-divider ui-btn ui-bar-b ui-corner-top ui-btn-up-undefined">Results</div>
      <div id="directions"></div>
      <div class="ui-li ui-li-divider ui-btn ui-bar-b ui-corner-bottom ui-btn-up-undefined"></div>
    </div>

</div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

I found this snippet in the 'basic map' section and applied it to the 'Direction Map' section:

```
self.addMarker({'position': this.get('map').getCenter() }).click(function() {
self.openInfoWindow({ 'content': 'Hello World!' }, this);
});
```

That goes right under:

```
var self = this
```